# Creating a function that error handles pandas filtering and exporting values into an Excel cell

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling

I've created a python program that scrapes data from a lot of web sources and aggregates the results together into a data frame. I'm now trying to put the results of the aggregated table into an Excel spreadsheet and defining what data to put in what cells.

The problem I have is that sometimes data will be missing from the data frame because it doesn't exist on the website. Which causes an IndexError when I try to filter/locate it within the pandas data frame.

To fix this problem I created a try/except statement to return a blank value to Excel when an IndexError has occurred. However, this means that for everytime I want to insert a value into an Excel cell I have to repeat code. To reduce the number of lines I've decided to write a function that will do the error handling and inserting of the value instead of doing multiple try/except statements. The problem is that the function isn't doing what I expect it to do as shown below with the # Does work and # Doesn't work examples.

I'd expect to be able to use cell_insert(cell, data) to insert data into the cell and be able to handle some specific errors for me. Perhaps there is something syntactic that i'm misunderstanding?

```
import pandas as pd

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

df_data = {
           'year_month': ['2019-06', '2019-06', '2019-06', '2019-06', '2019-06'],
           'lead_source': ['C', 'IH', 'INH', 'INH', 'MV'],
           'status': ['Lead', 'Lead', 'Lead', 'Refund', 'Lead'],
           'leads': [12, 7, 51, 2, 15],
           'total': [140, 280, 918, 36, 150]
           }
df = pd.DataFrame(df_data)

# Does work
try:
    ws['A1'] = df[(df['lead_source'] == 'C') & (df['status'] == 'Lead')].iloc[0]['total']
except IndexError:
    ws['A1'] = ''

try:
    ws['A2'] = df[(df['lead_source'] == 'C') & (df['status'] == 'Refund')].iloc[0]['total']
except IndexError:
    ws['A2'] = ''

# Doesn't work
# def cell_insert(cell, data):
#     try:
#         ws[cell] = data
#     except IndexError:
#         ws[cell] = ''
#
# cell_insert('A2', df[(df['lead_source'] == 'C') & (df['status'] == 'Refund')].iloc[0]['total'])

wb.save("stackoverflow.xlsx")
```

Comment: `Errors should never pass silently;print(them)`

Comment: Just changed my code around a bit and commented out the part that I'm confused about. Does this make it easier? I don't fully understand your comment. Thanks.

Comment: When you call the function you're getting an error before the data even gets passed to the function. If the second argument raises an IndexError it's never going to get passed in the function.

Comment: Is there anyway I can pass it to the function before it gets evaluated?

Comment: @RyanDavies see my answer below.

Comment: @Ryan Its [PEP20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) ; You should print the errors and add here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the function you're getting an error before the data even gets passed to the function. If the second argument raises an IndexError it's never going to get passed in the function.

For example try:

```
print(df[(df['lead_source'] == 'C') & (df['status'] == 'Refund')].iloc[0]['total'])
#This will not print and return an error because the print function will never receive the input because it evaluates to an error.
```

One admittedly clumsy workaround is to pass it as a string and use [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

```
def cell_insert(cell, data):
    #pass data as a string
    try:
        eval(data)
    except IndexError:
        data="''"
    ws[cell] = eval(data)
```

You would call this with quotes around your entry

```
cell_insert('A2', "df[(df['lead_source'] == 'C') & (df['status'] == 'Refund')].iloc[0]['total']")
#this should work
```

It's important not to mix up single and double quotes. Use double quotes for the outside and single for the actual call to the dataframe or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks this has answered my question! Although its opened up another problem if you want more points?

Comment: Also you have to change ws[cell] = data to ws[cell] = eval(data) else it just passes the string